# Is unique foreign keys across multiple tables via normalization and without null columns possible?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

This is a relational database design question, not specific to any RDBMS. A simplified case:

I have two tables Cars and Trucks. They have both have a column, say RegistrationNumber, that must be unique across the two tables.
This could probably be enforced with some insert/update triggers, but I'm looking for a more "clean" solution if possible.

One way to achieve this could be to add a third table, Vehicles, that holds the RegistrationNumber column, then add two additional columns to Vehicles, CarID and TruckID. But then for each row in Vehicles, one of the columns CarID or TruckID would always be NULL, because a RegistrationNumber applies to either a Car or a Truck leaving the other column with a NULL value.

Is there anyway to enforce a unique RegistrationNumber value across multiple tables, without introducing NULL columns or relying on triggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  Having the third table, `Vehicles` is definitely part of the solution.  The second part is guaranteeing that a vehicle is either a car or a truck, but not both.

One method is the "list-all-the-possibilities" method.  This is what you propose with two columns.  In addition, this should have a constraint to verify that only one of the ids is filled in.  A similar approach is to have the `CarId` and `TruckId` actually be the `VehicleId`.  This reduces the number of different ids floating around.

Another approach uses composite keys.  The idea is:

```
create table Vehicles (
    Vehicle int primary key,
    Registration varchar(255),
    Type varchar(255),
    constraint chk_type check (type in ('car', 'truck')),
    constraint unq_type_Vehicle unique (type, vehicle), -- this is redundant, but necessary
    . . .
);

create table car (
    VehicleId int,
    Type varchar(255), -- always 'car' in this table
    constraint fk_car_vehicle foreign key (VehicleId) references Vehicles(VehicleId),
    constraint fk_car_vehicle_type foreign key (Type, VehicleId) references Vehicles(Type, VehicleId)
);
```

Comment: Interesting solutions. However I don't really like the idea of having a column in a table that holds the exact same value for all rows (your Type column solution).
If I understand your other solution correctly, you suggest that the VehicleID (primary key in Vehicles) should be a reference to the primary key in either Cars or Trucks. I guess this cannot be achieved with referential integrity as a column - VehicleID - cannot reference two columns? I am probably misunderstanding your solution..?

Comment: Well, thanks for your suggestions. I guess there is no simple clean solution to this one.

Comment: @HenrikNielsen . . . Shared primary keys don't guarantee that a vehicle is not both a truck and a car.   One method is to use triggers.  Another is to use the method described in this answer.  In some databases (notably SQL Server) no space actually needs to be used for the extra column.  Alternatively, it could be a single character or tinyint.

Comment: Yes, I could use triggers to enforce the rule, but as stated in the question this is something I wish to avoid. However, digging deeper into the subject of class-table-inheritance I have come to realize that this is a lot like your suggestion above. I know that the shared primary key wouldn't guarantee that a vehicle isn't both a truck and a car, but I guess this could be solved with having a check constraint in the cars and truck tables to ensure that the type part of the key is a car or a truck respectively.

Comment: @HenrikNielsen . . . A check constraint would require a user-defined function to reference another table.  You may discover that the solution in my answer is the simplest that does everything you want.

Comment: Your absolutely right. Played around with it, found a solution I was happy with and I've just come to realize it is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Instead of a check constraint on vehicles, you could use a tiny int for index and refer to a separate vehichle_type table via a FK.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the third table Vehicles containing a single column RegistratioNumber on which you apply the unique constraint, then on the existing tables - Cars and Trucks - use the RegistrationNumber as a foreign key on the Vehicles table. In this way you don't need an extra id, avoid the null problem and enforce the uniqueness of the registration number.

**Update** - this solution doesn't prevent a car and a truck to share the same registration number. To enforce this constraint you need to add either triggers or logic beyond plain SQL. Otherwise you may want to take a look at Gordon's solution that involves Composite Foreign Keys.

Comment: This is correct.  If `RegistrationNumber` is `UNIQUE` in `Vehicles` there's no reason not to make it the `PRIMARY KEY` in that table and, if it's the `PRIMARY KEY` in that table, there's no reason not to make it *both* the `PRIMARY` *and* `FOREIGN KEY` in both `Cars` and `Trucks`.

Comment: @MaxP: Yes, I thought of that too, but as I see it, then there would be no way to enforce that the same registration number isn't referenced from both the Cars and The Trucks table?

Comment: Alas, this doesn't prevent a vehicle from being both a car and a truck.

Comment: Yes, my solution doesn't prevent a vehicle from being both a car and a truck. To enforce this constraint on my solution you need some triggers or some additional logic outside the plain SQL. Composite key solution by Gordon seems to be the most complete solution if you accept to pay the extra space for car/truck columns as parts of the composite foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

See the following tags:  [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

You have already outlined class table inheritance in your question.  The tag will just add a few details, and show you some other questions whose answers may help.

Shared primary key is a handy way of enforcing the one-to-one nature of IS-A relationships such as the relationship between a vehicle and a truck.  It also allows a foreign key in some other table to reference a vehicle and also a truck or a car, as the case may be.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to get. I wasn't aware of these concepts. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.